# how to loop one thread group until another thread group completes

Tags: jmeter

I have a thread group that does stuff for X number of loops. I have 2 other thread groups that I want to loop until the first thread group has completed.

How can I synchronize the other thread groups to only loop until the first thread group has completed it's loops?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will need to look at using IF Controller.  This might work for you:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller

Or the While:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller

Comment: i'm thinking while, but i still don't see how to use it to make it happen